# Shorthand for adding type to Observable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Some Background

Oftentimes with typescript, I'll declare an object shape in shorthand. Instead of making an interface, and then saying that the object is of that type, I just say:

```
object: { fizz: boolean, buzz: boolean } = { fizz: false, buzz: true }
```

That makes a lot of sense to me from a code-length perspective, for the case when I'm only going to use that object shape one time.

### The Question

Is there a way to tell an rxjs Observable an object shape in a similar way? I'd think it would be something like:

```
public getBazz(): Observable<{ fizz: boolean, buzz: boolean }> { ... }
```

But Typescript doesn't like that particular format, and I'm tired of guessing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of TS are you using?

The syntax you are suggesting seems to work for me on a fresh [JSbin using latest Typescript and RxJS v 5.03](http://jsbin.com/wakehisuqa/edit?js,console)

```
var r : Observable<{prop: string}> = Rx.Observable.from([
  {prop: 'hello'},
  {prop: 'world'},
]);

r.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: VS Code was using an older version of TS, defined by the workspace instead of the default TS version. Thanks!